# Is there a way to prevent std::vector from de-allocating memory dynamically when a resize occurs?

Tags: c++, vector

I would like to use std::vector in place of raw C arrays, in order to avoid cluttering up my code.

However, one of the setbacks with std::vector's dynamism is that the underlying data can't reliably be assumed to remain at the same location in RAM.  For example:

Say I have three vectors of chars stored in 9 bytes of memory:

A[0] A[1] A[2] | B[0] B[1] B[2] | C[0] C[1] C[2]

Given the way B is located, snugly in-between A and C, it's reasonable to assume that if B increases in size, the entire contents would move to a different location in memory, as opposed to the implementation of std::vector using any non-sequential storage of data.  I'm happy enough that std::vector doesn't do this non-sequential storage stuff, because that means the underlying data structure remains the array, which can be maximally efficient.

The problem with how std::vector would move B in the above scenario relates to what it does after this move: it frees the memory locations where B's 3 items were previously located.  This led to a bug in my code, as I was using pointers into the vector in other locations.  These pointers became invalid shortly after a resize, when the memory was freed.  A segmentation fault then followed.

My question: is there a way to prevent std::vector from freeing memory when it re-sizes?  Even if the memory overhead therefore increases, this would be fine in my use-case.

Alternatively, are there any other C++ data-structures you would recommend that do this?

Comment: Is there a maximum size the `vector` can ever have that is known at creation time? `reserve` is a common way to handle this. `std::deque` is also a viable replacement for a collection that only grows, never shrinks, because it *never* has to move elements in that scenario, and has most of the big-O performance guarantees of `std::vector` (though with higher constant factors).

Comment: "_if B increases in size_": How can that possibly happen? Objects have fixed size. Or do you mean that you add another element represented by `B[3]` to the vector? "_can't reliably be assumed to remain at the same location in RAM_": The rules for `std::vector` are pretty much exactly the same as a custom C-style implementation with dynamic arrays. You can either set the maximum size first and be guaranteed that there won't be reallocations or you permit arbitrary growth and have to consider reallocations a possibility (just like using `realloc` in C).

Comment: You are concerned about vectors containing a few bytes, when the structure for the vector itself is the size of 3 pointers, and there are overheads in the allocator too. If you want a random-access container that doesn't relocate its contents on resize, consider `std::deque`.

Comment: A reallocation is an intrinsic, built-in attribute of what vectors are, and how they work. It is expected that when writing C++ code that uses vectors, the  vectors' requirements are known and taken account for. If a bug occurs because someone forgot about vector reallocation the problem is not with the vector. This is how vectors work, and nothing can be done to change how they work. If reallocation is not desirable, one can use `std::list`, or some other container, but they wouldn't get random access iterators, of course.

Comment: "_it frees the memory locations where B's 3 items were previously located._": It can't free only the `B`'s. Either it moves all old contents to a new allocation and frees all of the old object, or all pointers remain valid. Again, just like `realloc`.

Comment: @user17732522 B could increase in size if a 4th item was added to it using `push_back`.  I was under the impression that using `reserve` with `std::vector` does not indicate we are setting a max size?  I.e. it just ensures we do a large enough malloc in advance.  Later `push_back` calls can then increase the underlying memory used if necessary.  Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @SeánHealy I assumed that all of `A[0] A[1] A[2] | B[0] B[1] B[2] | C[0] C[1] C[2]` represents your vector in the question. What are the items left and right from `|` supposed to represent if not part of the `B` vector that you are talking about?  "_Later push_back calls can then increase the underlying memory used if necessary._": No, only if the reserved slots are used up. What else would be the point of upfront reserving memory? If you reserve the maximum number of elements you will ever put into the vector, then there won't ever be a reallocation, just like in the simple C approach.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, I do have an estimate for `reserve`, but it's not iron-clad, so I'm still looking for data structures that leave the old locations alone when a new item is added and a re-shuffling happens.

Comment: @SeánHealy: Yeah, as I mentioned, `std::deque` gives you that, so long as the collection only grows, you're never removing stuff from the middle or anything, or removing items from the end that are still actively referenced from elsewhere. It's random access, it's just higher overhead on memory, and more pointer-chasing to look up an element (a fixed amount of pointer-chasing, so it's still `O(1)` indexing, just higher constant factors).

Comment: @user17732522 The pipe-separated example represents three vectors, each stored in adjacent memory.  This example was necessary for me to describe what I meant in this question: without this close proximity, the resizing of the B vector might not result in its contents being lifted to a new memory location (and the old memory subsequently freed).  Apologies: maybe the explainer of the pipe-separated example didn't make this clear enough.

Comment: I use `std::deque` all the time. It's super useful, and can also mitigate issues with memory fragmentation when filling a container with loads of stuff.

Comment: @SeánHealy I am not sure whether you are looking to reproduce some C implemented data structure or looking for an alternative data structure. If you just want to know what has already been implemented in the standard library see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container, specifically you would be interested in the table about "Iterator invalidation" or in your case rather "reference invalidation". But of course fewer invalidations always come with a trade-off in some other area, e.g. time complexity of certain operations.

Comment: @SeánHealy You can't store the contents of multiple vectors adjacent in memory. Each vector performs a separate allocation for its elements with one indirection. (Exceptions apply to some degree if you use a custom allocator, which I'll assume you don't.)

Comment: Technically you can, sort of. If you use a custom allocator. This whole thing is starting to smell like XY Problem to me.

Comment: A very simple solution is that instead of storing pointers into your vectors, just store indices.

Comment: Turn it around: "Why would it be?"

Comment: @ShadowRanger `std::deque` sounds good, but I'm really looking for a structure that doesn't use links, except when absolutely necessary, like when the resize bumps into other allocated memory.  The way I understand deque, it involves a link between each element.  Ideally, I would like a structure that only links when the list needs to grow.

Comment: @SeánHealy Have you looked at how `std::deque` works? How else would you implement your requirement in the last comment?

Comment: No, it has links between blocks of elements, and blocks are indexed such that random access is O(1). But you do not have the guarantee of sequential storage, so if your pointers expect to find anything else from the container not at that specific address, all bets are off.

Comment: @SeánHealy: You're thinking of `std::list`, and/or something like Python's `collections.deque` (which is similar to `std::deque` in that it uses linked blocks, but dissimilar in that there is no top level index that makes indexing `O(1)`). `std::deque` doesn't involve the sort of `O(n)` overheads you seem to be expecting.

Comment: Look at how crazy the comments section goes when someone doesn't provide a real code example...

Comment: @paddy I was considering the storing of indices, but read somewhere that this approach is harder for the g++ compiler to optimise in comparison to pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from calling `.reserve` with a value larger than the `vector` will ever get, `vector` won't do this for you, so if there is no known maximum possible size, `std::vector` is not an option.

It sounds like you want `std::deque` here. It has all the big-O performance guarantees of `std::vector` (except appends and pops from the end are *actually* `O(1)`, rather than amortized `O(1)`), and as long as it's only growing, never shrinking, any given element is never moved to new memory (because under the hood, it's allocating additional non-adjacent blocks of memory, rather than reallocating a single contiguous block). It pays for this with higher baseline memory overhead (though nowhere near what `std::list` pays as it grows), and higher *fixed* overhead for all operations (e.g. indexing a `std::vector` only requires chasing a single pointer, while indexing a `std::deque` might take three such pointer-chasing operations, but it would be a *fixed* three, not like `std::list` where it scales with collection size), but it's usually fast enough, and it would get you the memory location stability guarantees you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks @ShadowRanger… bit of a follow-up… is there really much point in using `std::vector` if the max size is known in advance and applied via `reserve`, i.e. as opposed to plain C arrays?

Comment: @SeánHealy: Because the actual objects in it may not be default-constructable. Because they may occupy additional memory if constructed, and you don't want to occupy that memory unless you actually have a useful object to put there. Because you `reserve`d for 10x what you think you'll need, knowing you'll *never* need *that* much, and if you just reserve it, not construct into it, on many systems (e.g. Linux), that memory is copy-on-write mapped to the zero-page, so it's not actually consuming real memory (just address space) until the page it's in is written to.

Comment: Thanks, ShadowRanger, that has helped me a lot!  I didn't know reserving with vectors could have these memory saving benefits on Linux.  I do wonder if this carries a small amount of overhead, because surely the copy-on-write must involve more operations than populating into a plain C array.  I will however be using vectors as a result of your comment here.

Regarding your points about objects, I presume this relates to the object-oriented elements of C++.  In this case I didn't know malloc'ing would call constructors by default.  I'm actually just using structs in my code, so no biggie here

Comment: @SeánHealy: The copy-on-write mechanism is used for *every* OS memory request from the operating system, so there's no extra overhead over the plain C array, the plain C array, when the memory request is large enough, is *also* going to use copy-on-write maps of the zero-page, because that's the only way Linux actually gives memory to your program (at least on the heap). This isn't specific to C++ or `vector`s at all, it's how all large allocations will behave if the memory is never written to.

Comment: Thanks @ShadowRanger!  Based on this information, i.e. since plain C arrays also use copy-on-write, would that not negate the memory-saving benefits of using `reserve` with `std::vector`?  I.e. would a plain C array also use the zero-page after `malloc`, until a time when items start getting written into the array memory addresses?

Comment: @SeánHealy: The plain C array doesn't track its own useful size, doesn't let you leave anything but the simple POD stuff uninitialized, and doesn't work at all if you lack a default constructor.

Comment: @SeánHealy You haven't provided a single concrete example of how you're applying this stuff in practice. The nearest example you gave is storing a tiny number of bytes in a container. The overhead of all the pointers you maintain for the containers and your indexes in this case completely outweighs any savings you think you're getting by not over-allocating to begin with. As with any engineering topics related to optimization, an appropriate solution depends on many factors and most of those factors relate to very specific design requirements. You should not approach this in general terms.